# Replaceable string with special characters

Tags: javascript

I have a string let's say

```
var str = "blah blah [ID] blah [ID]";
```

Now, i want to replace "[ID]" and tried as below

```
str = str.replace("[ID]", "");
```

however, it replaces only the first occurrence

then, i tried global replacement as below

```
str = str.replace(/[ID]/g, "");
```

But, no luck. Please help

Comment: *"But, no luck"* What happened? http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is a good source for learning some regex basics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[` and `]` have [special meaning](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) in regular expressions, so they have to be escaped with backslashes:

```
str = str.replace(/\[ID\]/g, "");
```

Comment: Exactly this is what i want. Thanks @nnnnnn